# If f(x) is a permutation polynomial defined over the finite field GF(q), then so is g(x) = a f(x + b) + c for all a ≠ 0, b and c in GF(q)

Tags: polynomials, permutations, finite-fields

"If f(x) is a permutation polynomial defined over the finite field GF(q), then so is g(x) = a f(x + b) + c for all a ≠ 0, b and c in GF(q)"

Hey guys,

I've been seeing this statement as an remark or Lemma in lots of different papers, but never managed to find proof.

My knowledge about finite fields ist limited, and I'd be happy to proof the statement myself, don't know how to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to do with finite fields, really. It is an instance of the general fact that composing two or more permutations is automatically a permutation. Do youu see which three permutations are getting combined here?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I assume you combine the Permutations (Addition of b), (Multiplication by a) and (Addition of c), but wasn't sure, if those are actually permutations when operating an a finite field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - Four, not three. Add, $f$, multiply, add.

Comment: A permutation is just an invertible function from the set to itself. The polynomial $x+a$ has an inverse $x-a$. The polynomial $a\cdot x$ has an inverse $a^{-1}\cdot x$ when $a\neq0$. Hence, these are permutation polynomials.

Comment: @mr_e_man I used $t\mapsto at+c$ as the outermost one. But you are right in that we can further split that into two parts.

Comment: Correct @Thomas. You can verify that they are permutations using the field axioms (group axioms suffice in the case of the translation), or find the inverse of a linear polynomial explicitly. Oh, and you used $f$ in the composition, too.